# Intuition advice: How does the transpose affect a real matrix's elementary vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, intuition

I'm really good at visualizing things and it's how linear algebra really makes sense to me, but I had the intuition that if you have a matrix A with a col space and a nullspace, if you take the transpose of A, you now essentially swapped your col space and null space (which I guess I'm implying that I think the null space is my row space). I'm pretty sure I'm going wrong somewhere and someone correct my misunderstanding?

I'm trying to think why

$(Col(A))^⊥ = Null(A^T)$

Comment: when you take the transpose, you swap the column space with the row space

Comment: What's if it's exactly the same thing before and after? All the same spaces involved with slightly different labeling. We're basically just writing it vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: how does the row space generally overlap with the col space? I guess that would depend on whether or not the matrix is symmetric or non square, im going to try playing around with this a little more. I'm just wondering if there's an easy intuition im missing

Comment: The only relation guaranteed to hold between the row space and the column space is that they have the same dimension. As for the null space, if $v$ is perpendicular to everything in the row space, then it's perpendicular to every row, so, if you think about how matrix multiplication works, it's in the null space. And conversely if $v$ is in the null space, then it's perpendicular to each row, so it's perpendicular to everything in the row space.

Comment: If $A$ is a real $m \times n$ matrix, then the row space of $A$ is isomorphic to the column space of $A$, and $A$ itself provides the isomorphism. (You can check that the mapping $x \mapsto Ax$ is an isomorphism from the range of $A^T$ to the range of $A$.)